Problema Warning: Undefined array key (validar form php ajax js)
La página de la validación no me recibe el arreglo de los datos del formulario, después de haber pasado por el Js, y este al enviarlos al php por ajax, en esta última, no me aparecen los datos para validar.
Podrian ayudarme?.
pagina index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fuentes/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Outer Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">
                <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
                    <div class="card-body p-0">
                        <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="p-5">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <form action="#" method="POST" class="user">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="usuario">Nombre</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="nombre" name="nombre" 
 type="text" placeholder="Digite nombre de Usuario...">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" autocomplete="on">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember
                                                    Me</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" value="Enviar" id="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                            Entrar
                                        </button>
                                        <hr>
                                    </form>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <a class="small" href="register.php">Create an Account!</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./codigo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

Esta es la página js valido una parte, y la otra, la envio por ajax a la página progreso.php.  // aqui si puedo cargar los valores que traigo del formulario...en la liena console.log muestro como se pasan del form al js...ver imagen
Codigo.js:
$('#Enviar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    nombre= $('#nombre').val();
    password= $('#password').val();
    console.log("matriz de datos de PHP",nombre, password);
    $.ajax({
        url:"proceso.php",
        type:'post',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{nombre:nombre,password:password},
        success:function(respuesta){ 
        },  
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
        },
    
        // código a ejecutar sin importar si la petición falló o no
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Petición realizada');}

    })
})

Esta es la página donde valido con la base de datos... pero como no me llega información, no puedo comparar.
Página validar:

<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_POST);
include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
  echo "La variable está definida.";
} else {
  echo "La variable no está definida.";
}
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
$password=$_POST['password'] ?? null;
var_dump($nombre);
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$nombre' AND password='$password' ";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();
if($resultado->rowCount() >= 1){
  $data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}else{
  $data=null;
}
echo "Estos datos fueron almacenados en la base de datos: <br> Nombre:".$nombre."<br>"."Correo: ".$password;
print json_encode($data);

Estos son los errores que me salen de la página en el navegador.
errores pagina proceso.php
array(0) { } 
La variable no está definida.
NULL 
Estos datos fueron almacenados en la base de datos:
Nombre:
Correo: null

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, gracias

Hola. Si analizas lo que pasas vía Ajax: data:{nom:nom,email:email}, los valores tienen las claves nom y email. Pero tú estás buscando en una clave mon aquí:  $mon=$_POST['mon'];, debes cambiarlo a $nom=$_POST['nom']; El Undefined array key "email"  no debería ocurrir, si es que nos estás mostrando el código .php del archivo correcto. Me extraña además que no arroje un Undefined variable $nom porque usas esa variable en la instrucción SQL pero nunca la declaras. Para depurar más a fondo pon un var_dump($_POST); después del session_start(); y dinos qué muestra?

hola, buenas tardes ...hice las correcciones que me planteas y aun asi nada,cambie todo
formulario:
<input type="text"  id="nombre" name="nombre"
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"
js
nombre= $('#nombre').val();
password= $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
url:'proceso.php',
type:"POST",
//datatype: "json",
data:{nombre:nombre,password:password},
valida.php
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
echo "La variable está definida.";
} else {
echo "La variable no está definida.";
}
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
$password=$_POST['password'] ?? null;

Para depurar más a fondo pon un var_dump($_POST); después del session_start(); y dinos qué muestra?       respuesta:  array(0) { }

Pon el nuevo código en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Si te sale array(0) { } significa que no se está enviando nada al archivo .php. ¿Depuraste del lado del cliente que nombre y password tienen valores, por ejemplo poniendo un alert(nombre); y un alert(password); después de crear las variables y antes de lanzar la petición Ajax? Verifica además que la ruta del archivo .php sea la correcta con respecto a la ruta donde se encuentra el código Javascript. Según esto: url:"proceso.php" ambos archivos deben estar en la misma carpeta. También, puede que ...

... se haya quedado en memoria el código viejo. Para descartar eso, prueba en una nueva ventana en modo incógnito, o cambiando la URL, mandando nuevos parámetros, por ejemplo: https://www.elDominio/laCarpeta/elArchivo.php?nuevoParametro=nuevoValor

@JOSETOMASVERGARADIAZ, si la versión de jQuery es mayor a la 1.9, entonces para enviar los datos por POST tenes que indicar method: 'POST'.

ya modifique el codigo aqui...voy editando este post con sus aportes....como ven si tengo los valores que traigo del form al js...lo mando a imprimir en consola (linea 5 codigo.js) antesde enviarlos por ajax....pero aun no se cargan en la pagina final para validar......por cierto simpre  recargo la página y limpio su caché, presionando la combinación de teclas Ctrl + F5.
